# If my input is January and year is 2016 then it need to take input as 01-jan-16to 31-jan-16

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to do that in my procedure. Customer mention January and the year. My procedure received only month and year, but I need to convert this month and year in to 01-month-year to 31-month-year.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Sry..i don't have code to show you..Usually we filter table using date...so I need to do that...If customer choose January and the year 2016..then I need to convert like 01-Jan-2016 to 31-Jan-16..so that I can able to filter in my table

Comment: You need to show some code like what type you receive the date etc. so we can replicate it

Comment: Can you show some example...I didn't understand what type you receive the date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_date` function to convert string to date (first date of the month) and then use `add_month` to add 1 month and then -1 day to calculate last day of the month (Or use `last_day` function) as following:

```
Start_date := to_date(in_month|| '-' || in_year,'month-yyyy');
End_date := last_day(start_date);
-- or
End_date := add_months(start_date,1) - 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: This answer doesn't work for Oracle DB, only Java DB.

The below can be ignored:

According to Oracle's **java-db** Docs' [Month Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefmonthfunc.html) & [Year Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefyearfunc.html)

you should be able to solve your issue by simply adding the following conditions to your Query:

```
WHERE 
  YEAR(your_date_column) = %customer_input_year_as_number% 
AND 
  MONTH(your_date_column) = %customer_input_month_as_number%
```

It'd be easier to help you if you could show us what you've tried so far, this answer is purely based off of the oracle docs and should **in theory** work for your case.

Comment: `YEAR` and `MONTH` are [MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and not Oracle functions.

Comment: I'm literally linking to https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0 in my answer.
@MT0

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c68262c91c81390a26cd0adff054e83c) and it doesn't work because that isn't the documentation page for Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: @Campiotti Docs you have attached are Java DB, not Oracle DB.

Comment: Usually we received from_date and to_date as a input like (01-jan-16 and 31-jan-16)from customer..so I can easily use the date in where clause...But if customer only select the month and year without specifying the date, I received January and the year. How to convert this input to 01-jan-16 and 31-jan-16..

Comment: ah ok thanks @MT0 & \@ErgiNushi for the heads up, I'll edit my answer.

\@vinothkumar you can ignore my answer as it doesn't work for the DB you're using however if it were compatible then it should've worked since you're only checking year and month and thus don't need to check if it's within the 1st or 31st day of said month because **you're directly checking if it's in the month**.